# Box constrained maximization using Kuhn tucker

Tags: optimization, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have to maximize the following function -

Max A $C_1^{-m}/{-m}$ + (1-A) $C_2^{-m}/{-m}$

Subject to,

$C_1$ ≤ 5(1-x) + x

$C_2$ ≤ 3(1-x) + 7x

1≤x≤10

I wrote it as:
L(x) = f(x) - $λ_1$($C_1$ - 5(1-x) + x) - $λ_2$($C_2$ - 3(1-x) + 7x) - $λ_3$(x-1) - $λ_4$(x-10)

Can I write last constraint as partioned into $λ_3$ and $λ_4$. Is there some other way to introduce such box constraints into the same problem?

Comment: Would you explain how $A\frac{C_1^{-m}}{-m}+(1-A)\frac{C_2^{-m}}{-m}$ depends on $x$?

Comment: @Cesareo Thanks for noticing! I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Considering

$$
L(x,\lambda,\epsilon) = \lambda_1(C_1-5(1-x)-x-\epsilon_1^2)+\lambda_2(C_2-3(1-x)-7x-\epsilon_2^2)+\lambda_3(1-x-\epsilon_3^2)+\lambda_4(x-10-\epsilon_4^2)
$$

with $\epsilon_k$ convenient slack variables, the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \cases{4\lambda_1-4\lambda_2-\lambda_3+\lambda_4 = 0\\
C_1-5(1-x)-x-\epsilon_1^2 = 0\\
C_2-3(1-x)-7x-\epsilon_2^2 = 0\\
1-x-\epsilon_3^2 = 0\\
x-10-\epsilon_4^2 = 0\\
\lambda_1\epsilon_1 = 0\\
\lambda_2\epsilon_2 = 0\\
\lambda_3\epsilon_3 = 0\\
\lambda_4\epsilon_4 = 0
}
$$

and the feasible solutions are those observing $\epsilon_k^2 \ge 0$ for $k = 1,2,3,4$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
x & \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & \lambda_4 & \epsilon_1^2 & \epsilon_2^2 & \epsilon_3^2 & \epsilon_4^2\\
 \frac{5-C_1}{4}& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & C_1+C_2-8 & \frac{C_1-1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4}
   (C_2+35) \\
 \frac{C_2-3}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & C_1+C_2-8 & 0 & \frac{7-C_2}{4} & \frac{C_2-43}{4} \\
 x & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & C_1+4 x-5 & C_2-4 x-3 & 1-x & x-10 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks you for the expanded solution

Comment: Can you please explain why haven't you written maximing function f(x) in L(x). Why did you just directly start off with all the constraints?

Comment: Because $A\frac{C_1^{-m}}{-m}+(1-A)\frac{C_2^{-m}}{-m}$ does not depends on $x,\lambda,\epsilon$ The purpose in this kind of problems is to find solution points pertaining to the feasible region.

Comment: Okay! I got it now

Answer (score 0):

Is your function constant?
If I read correctly you have
\begin{align*}
\underset{\text{w.r.t}\; x\in \mathbb{R}}{\text{maximise}}\; &\;-A\,\dfrac{C_1^{-m}}{m} -(1-A)\dfrac{C_2^{-m}}{m} = \gamma\\
\text{subj.to}&\quad h_1(x)\leq 0\\
&\quad h_2(x)(x)\leq 0\\
&\quad \alpha\leq h_3(x) \leq \beta
\end{align*}
Maximizing a constant function under some constraints is called a satisfiability problem; any reachable value will attain the maximum (and minimum) of $\gamma$.
Your method of putting 
$$\alpha\leq h_3(x) \leq \beta \;\iff\; \alpha - h_3(x) \leq 0\; \text{and} \;  h_3(x) - \beta \leq 0 $$
Before putting the problem into Lagrangian form is the go-to solution in most cases if $f$ is non constant!

Comment: Sorry for being a little slow in understanding but what do you mean by 'before putting the problem into legrangian form'? How should I rewrite my solution to cater to what you just said?

Comment: No you implicitly did what I just said: you split the inequalities into two!